# Cannot Send Long Command in bash Script Expect

Tags: php, exec, expect, telnet

I'm having trouble in sending long commands with my expect script. I'm using telnet to access the router:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f
#
#

spawn telnet 192.168.0.5

expect {
  "login:"
    {
        send "admin\r"
        expect "Password:"
        send "admin\r"

        expect ">"
        send "enable\r"
        expect "Password:"
        send "\r"

        # My Command
        expect "#"
        send "terminal length 0\r"
        expect "#"
        send "show running-config | include ip nat pool-group\r"
    }
}

expect "#"
send "exit\r"
```

I'm using exec in php to run the script above

```
<?php
exec(mybinfile , $returnvalue);
print_r($returnvalue);
```

When I check the output, it looks like the incorrect command has been sent. But still, it is working. Why does it output it like that?

The result looks like this:

```
[14] => R1#terminal length 0
[15] => R1#show running-config | include ip nat pool-gro$ng-config | include ip nat pool-grou          $ng-config | include ip nat pool-group
```

I tried to reduce the number of characters in my command like the example below and it is fine:

```
show running-config | include ip nat pool-gro
```

Will I encounter problems if that is the output I can see in `print_r`?

Comment: `Will I encounter problems if that is the output I can see in print_r?` No. There will be no problem, it's just how expect works. The longer the string is, the more gibberish it will become.

Comment: It's a combination of the remove device, telnet itself, and how expect captures the output from telnet. It's not about "how expect works" and "gibberish". When you telnet to that device "manually", does some of the text show up as bold or highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to issuing the `terminal length 0` command, you can also issue the `terminal width 511` command to prevent line wrapping. This resolved a similar issue for us.

From [the documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa81/command/ref/refgd/t.html#wp1483720):

> To set the width for displaying information during console sessions, use the **terminal width** command in global configuration mode. To disable, use the **no** form of this command.
>
> **terminal width** *columns*
>
> **no terminal width** *columns*

See also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/389575/cisco-asa-command-length) on ServerFault.